# SQL Server: Copying column within table

Tags: sql, copying

What is the easiest way to copy the all the values from a column in a table to another column in the same table?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

With a single statement (if the columns have the same datatype)

```
UPDATE <tablename>
SET <destination column name> = <source column name>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to create the new column ?

Comment: NOTE: You need to have the destination column already created.

Answer (score 15):

This script will update ALL values in the field1 with the values from the field2 in the corresponding row

```
UPDATE table SET field1 = field2
```