# Loop for updating rows with a condition

Tags: sql, loops

I have 2  bit columns in a table *active* and *suspended*
The active column already contains values but the *suspended* column still null

How can I fill the *suspended* field with values that is opposite of *active*?

I was stuck in this code..

```
 Declare @suspended bit;

 --some conditions

 Update Users_mock
 Set Suspended = @Suspended;
```

Comment: Opposite means 0 for 1 and 1 for 0?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173717/sql-server-copying-column-within-table and use 'case' to update the col

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
Update Users_mock
Set Suspended = 1-Active;
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `case` statement should work:

```
Update userM
Set suspend = case active when 0 then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check this [Update sql bit field in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879999/update-sql-bit-field-in-database).

It says, **Bits in SQL Server are always stored as 1 or 0 in a bitmap. **

You may use a `where`, `if-else` or `case` to update the column.

Answer (score 1):

select abs(CONVERT(int,@suspended)-1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update Users_mock
set Suspended = case when active=1 THEN 0
else 1
end
```